# how to use both if and group by together to map different values into a different value?

Tags: if-statement, indexing, offset, partition, group

[image]

how can i calculate the final decision from excel into power bi

basically..if i have same auth id on same replied and one was approved whereas the other was denied..then the final decision is approved and denied maps to partially denied.

how to do this in power bi?

i tried grouping. it did not work because then i lose my approved rows.

the offset function needs a numeric values (adding, multiplying) but i dont have any numeric valuse